# Error in current measurement

Tags: current, transformer, measurement, error, instrumentation

I am measuring the error ratio and phase displacement in a CT. The experimental circuit is the next.

[image: Circuit used]

The results with the oscilloscope show that the error ratio is not within the limits of the class for the CT. I have also filtered the signals and the result is the same. However, the phase is within the limits.

I also connected two true RMS multimeters in the primary and secondary side. Results obtained show that the error ratio is within the limits.

My question is why I can't obtain accurate results through the shunt resistors when they have an accuracy of 0.25%.

I can't use the multimeter because I need the phase displacement between primary and secondary side.

Thanks

Comment: Are you measuring 10 mV with your oscilloscope on the secondary? What probe are you using?

Comment: Hello, no. The shunt resistors value is 10 mohms. The voltage measured is the input for the oscilloscope. I am using a differential probe.

Comment: What probe? What sensitivity?

Comment: I am using the PicoConnect 441 . A passive differential probe with 1:1 ratio ,15 MHz bandwidth for precisely measuring voltages on ranges from ±10 mV to ±50 V.

Comment: Do you have better than 0.25 % voltage accuracy on your scope * probe error? I doubt it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question. The 0.25% is the accuracy of the shunt resistors. The probe does not specify its accuracy, however I have done the calculation and the accuracy of the oscilloscope is 2.02%. The mean squared error of this two is 2.03%.
The accuracy of the true rms multimeter is 1% for this current.

Comment: So your oscilloscope alone is ten times worse than the accuracy you're after? Then you simply can't tell if you are within spec using it. Same goes for the multimeter, but only by a factor of four.